# Delete Statement taking a too much time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

My sql Server 2008 table has more 5 million records.  I am deleting more than 4 million records in single statement.  It is taking more than an hour. Is this the best query to delete the records?

my delete query

```
delete From [Table] 
where SUBSTRING([Column_YYY],1,CHARINDEX(N'',[Column_YYY])-1) = '4'
```

Comment: It depends on your PC..your query has no issues

Comment: because it doesn't use `INDEX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that's not by any measure the best query.  Your substring starts with 1, and you're comparing against a SINGLE character, `'4'`!  To use an index on ColumnYYY, just change it to a LIKE clause letting the index quickly hunt down the first two characters.

```
delete [Table] 
where [Column_YYY] LIKE N'4%'
```

That would be true if that did not target 80% of your table, in which case SQL Server will completely scan the table anyway.  To prevent tempdb space issues or overly large transactions (locking), I would have broken it up into bits:

```
set nocount on
select 1;
while @@rowcount > 0
begin
    ;with x as (select top 100000 * from [Table] where [Column_YYY] LIKE N'4%')
    delete x;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

thats because your query needs to run the SUBSTRINGfuncion on every single row of the DB to check if it matches the condition. You should always avoid funcions on the WHERE clause. Even if you have indexes, they wont be used.

If it is taking that much and it a common operation you may consider persisting the result of that value on the DB and creating an index on it

EDIT:
unrelated to main question but still part of the discussion.
Index usage:
[image]

Comment: yes I said that. I mentioned indexing only if you persist the result of the substring function on a column and check it directly

Comment: you are wrong, check the print screen. It shows the index being used

Comment: your are using LIKE with %. My point on my answer was that the data should be persisted and then compared with the actuall to-be-deleted string. I've seem this work really well specially on dates where you have a date  field on a table and want to delete everything from month 5 for example, so you instead of running a delete where minth(column) = 5 you have a persisted calculated column with the month(column) formula and then do your checks on it.
FYI, If you run  delete testindex where value = '{80'; on your example, you'll see an index seek

Comment: maybe you are too full of yourself to even consider what I'm saying. I just ran: set rowcount 163840  and then update testindex set value = '{80' to make 80% of the data equals to '{80'. Then I rest rowcount and ran the delete. Again I  see an index seek. If you think I'm wasting your time fine, just dont answer anymore but I am providing you with evidence of what I'm saying that in this particular situation the index is being used. On your first query yes, you were right, but with a straight comparisson, SQL seems to be using the index.